# C++ Csv file doesn't load to vector properly, it seems to know the objects are there but does not display them

Tags: c++, csv, vector

I've been trying to read in a `*.csv` file to a `vector`, however it doesn't seem to work as such, it behaves that there are objects but doesn't display them and acts if they're empty.

This is the function to load the `*.csv` file.

```
void loadShoes()
{
fstream shoes;
shoes.open("shoes.txt", ios::in);
string shoeId;
string valueId;

    while (getline(shoes, shoeId, ','))
    {
        getline(shoes, valueId, ',');
        ShoeMap[shoeId] = valueId;

        if (shoeId == "ShoeLaceStyle")                                    
        {
            thefootwear.addShoe(ShoeMap);
        };
    }
}
```

This code is from the `main` that calls the function to load into a `vector` and then be displayed in a `simple UI`.

```
    else if (userInput == 3)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < thefootwear.vecNewShoe.size(); i++)
        {

            cout << i + 1 << " - " << thefootwear.vecNewShoe[i]->getShoeID() << "\n";
        }


        cout << "\nWhich Shoe would you like to view from the store?\n";
        cin >> userInput1;
        cout << "ShoeID - " << thefootwear.vecNewShoe[userInput1 - 1]->getShoeID() << "\n" << "ShoeName - " 
                            << thefootwear.vecNewShoe[userInput1 - 1]->getShoeName() << "\n" << "ShoeType - " 
                            << thefootwear.vecNewShoe[userInput1 - 1]->getShoeType() << "\n" << "ShoeSize - " 
                            << thefootwear.vecNewShoe[userInput1 - 1]->getShoeSize() << "\n" << "ShoeSoleStyle - "
                            << thefootwear.vecNewShoe[userInput1 - 1]->getShoeSoleStyle() << "\n" << "ShoeColour - " 
                            << thefootwear.vecNewShoe[userInput1 - 1]->getShoeColour() << "\n" << "ShoeLaceStyle - " 
                            << thefootwear.vecNewShoe[userInput1 - 1]->getShoeLaceStyle() << "\n";

    }
```

This is the `method` and `function` to add a `new shoe` with the required `variables`, in the `Footwear` class.

```
Shoe* Footwear::addShoe(map<string, string> ShoeMap)
{
Shoe* newShoe = new Shoe(ShoeMap["ShoeID"], ShoeMap["ShoeName"], ShoeMap["ShoeType"], ShoeMap["ShoeSize"], ShoeMap["ShoeSoleStyle"], ShoeMap["ShoeColour"], ShoeMap["ShoeLaceStyle"]);
vecNewShoe.push_back(newShoe);
return newShoe;

}
```

When I run the program, it displays the correct number of `shoes` currently in the `*.csv` file, however it fails to display their corresponding `Shoe ID` and I am, therefore, unable to access the variables related to the `Shoes`.

Comment: could you post all the code [here](http://ideone.com/) ?

Comment: You can't read CSV using `getline(shoes, shoeId, ',')` because the last field in a CSV record is not terminated with a comma.

Comment: Would I put all .h and .cpp files into the same input on ideone?

Comment: The end of the CSV does have a comma on mine or did you mean elsewhere?

Comment: CSV file called shoes.txt currently contains:  Shoe ID,1,Shoe Name,a,Shoe Type,a,Shoe Size,,Shoe Sole Style,a,Shoe Colour,a,Shoe Lace Style,a,

Comment: @NeilButterworth is right. may be you can have 2 loops. first to get the whole line(row) delimited by "\n" and second to get each column value delimited by ",".

Comment: So problem is in parsing `csv` right? @Danny

Comment: How would I go about resolving this then? I'm a bit unsure I'm fairly new to C++.

Comment: Can anyone help at all? Even some example code would help

Comment: Write or use a CSV parser. I have a simple one here - https://bitbucket.org/neilb/csvparse/src

Answer (score 0):

Speaking to your need rather than your specific question: Consider not writing your own custom CSV parser, but rather using a pre-existing C++ CSV parser library. There are [several popular ones on GitHub](https://github.com/search?l=C%2B%2B&q=CSV%20parser&type=Repositories&utf8=%E2%9C%93) for example.

This has the added benefit of being more robust against unexpected input contrivances (such as quoted numbers for example).